# Is there a tooltip library which lets me add tooltips to SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I want to add dynamic text and style to tooltips for elements of an SVG. I can do this by adding a div and styling it (red rectangle below). I would prefer to let a library handle it but they all seem to use the title attribute of elements which SVGs do not support (black rectangle below).

Can anyone suggest such a library?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("rect#2").mouseover(function(e) {
    var myText = "'jQuery' tooltip.";
    $("<div class='tooltip'>" + myText + "</div>").appendTo("body");
    $("div.tooltip").css({
      top: e.clientY,
      left: e.clientX
    });
  });
  $("rect#2").mouseout(function() {
    $("div.tooltip").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgDiv">
  <svg width="200" height="100">
    <rect id="1" x="30" y="30" width="50" height="50" title="myText" style="fill:black"/>
    <rect id="2" x="130" y="30" width="50" height="50" style="fill:red"/>
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  <div title="'title' tooltip.">div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I imagine most libraries will read a title attribute even if the element doesn't support it.

Comment: sorry unsure what exactly the problem is based on your code. Your red square "receives" tooltip (although it flickers) but black one has no tooltip, which I guess is expected base don your code. So what is not working for you?

Comment: One problem I have is having to manage instances of the tooltip disappearing off the edge of the screen if the svg is on the bottom or right hand side of the screen. Libraries usually have interesting options like "tracking the mouse" and looking like speech bubbles.

Comment: I also had a mouseout bug which resulted in the tooltip remaining visible if the mouse flicked across the widget, solved with a CSS hover workaround, as it takes a little while to retrieve the information for the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need a library for a simple case. I would do your snippet a bit differently:

- make div a display: none, pointer-events: none element of your DOM
- once mouseover happens - update its position and visibility
- handle dynamic messages by updating innerHTML parameter of tooltip DIV

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("rect#2").mouseover(function(e) {
    var myText = "'jQuery' tooltip.";
    $("div#tooltip").html(myText);
    $("div#tooltip").css({
      display: "inline-block",
      top: e.clientY,
      left: e.clientX
    });
  });
  $("rect#2").mouseout(function() {
    $("div#tooltip").css({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      display: "none",
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgDiv">
  <svg width="200" height="100">
    <rect id="1" x="30" y="30" width="50" height="50" title="myText" style="fill:black"/>
    <rect id="2" x="130" y="30" width="50" height="50" style="fill:red"/>
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">tooltip text</div>
</div>
```